# Why the file modes on OSX and Linux are different when cloning code with git

Tags: linux, git, macos, github

I cloned the same project from Github on my MacBook (Sierra) and Linux machine (Ubuntu 16.04), and I see the file mode on my MacBook is "-rw-r--r--", but in my Linux machine, it is "-rw-rw--r--".

Is there a way to make them consistent? Thanks!

Comment: Thing is: although Mac OS is a Unix, there are a lot of subtle differences; especially around file system topics; it is even possible to get to a system that does **not** really care about lower case versus UpperCase characters in file names. Long story short; you might need to do some serious research here. Maybe start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git cares only about the executable bit.  The rest is left to the system. Unix systems have a per-process `umask` value, set and maintained by the `umask` command, that says which permissions *not* to grant. `0022` and `0066` and `0077` are common settings for that.  My Arch linux default is `0022`, don't grant write privilege to anyone but me. It looks like your linux distro defaults to `0002`, don't grant write privilege to the general public, but allow it for you and your group.

So put `umask 0022` in your shell startup.  If you want it system-wide, look in `/etc/profile`, the Arch one runs any hooks in `/etc/profile.d` so you could add an override there.